# Sending SMS with GSM phone\modem using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sms, gsm

Is there an available API or functionality in cocoa where i can communicate with my GSM Phone to listen to any incoming SMS messages and be able to send messages myself. I'm trying to build an application for OSX SnowLeopard that can do this. Under the windows platform there are available API's that i can use to do this job for me. I just need hook up my mobile phone into my PC, configure the API to communicate with the phone thru one of the available COM Ports used by the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check my thoughts about it here: [How to send SMS from Mac terminal via GSM modem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115904/how-to-send-sms-from-mac-terminal-via-gsm-modem)

Comment: Thanks Anton. This is a lot of work. I hope someone out there comes up with a library which can do the job for the job. I'll be sharing my code when i get done, but it'l still be a while. thanks.